# How to create a list of methods?

Tags: c#, .net

How can I execute a method one by one in the order they were added to the `List<Action>`?

```
List<Action> actions = new List<Action>();

        List<int> listaInt = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            listaInt.Add(i);
            var entries = entries1.Select(d => string.Format("{0}", string.Join(",", d)));
            actions.Add(new Action(() => { 
                Console.WriteLine("counterList: " + string.Join(",", entries ));
            }));
        }
```

I want to execute every function, but with the list of integers(`List<int>`)

```
        foreach (Action action in actions) {
            action();
        }
```

Result:

```
listaInt: 0,1,2,3,4
listaInt: 0,1,2,3,4
listaInt: 0,1,2,3,4
listaInt: 0,1,2,3,4
listaInt: 0,1,2,3,4
```

Expected result:

```
listaInt: 0
listaInt: 0,1
listaInt: 0,1,2
listaInt: 0,1,2,3
listaInt: 0,1,2,3,4
```

Comment: You keep modifying the list. No wonder the output is `0,1,2,3,4` each time. You should familiarise yourself with the differences between value and reference types.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't entirely clear. But it seems like what you want is for each element (i.e. "snapshot") in the list to represent the original `List<int>`'s state at the time it was added to the action list.

If so, then the main problem here is that you are adding the reference to the original list. Any changes to that list later will still be observed in any copy of that reference, such as those you are adding.

If you want an actual "snapshot", then you need to make one. I.e. make a *copy* of the list when you add it to the action list. For example:

```cs
public static void TakeSnapShot(List<int> listaInt, int i) {

    GridSnapshotAction gridSnapshotAction = new GridSnapshotAction();
    List<int> listCopy = new List<int>(listaInt);

    gridSnapshotAction.AddAction(() => {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
        PrintLista(listCopy);
    });


    gridSnapshotActionList.Add(gridSnapshotAction);
}
```

There are other places in the code where you might make a copy. And there are other ways you could implement this. For example, if you were using [`ImmutableList<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablelist), then the original list reference would be the one getting updated, while each captured list would be the snapshot you want (and this approach would be somewhat more efficient, since `ImmutableList<T>` is optimized to share data between copies of the list when possible).

The bottom line is: if you want separate copies of the list object, you need to do something to make sure you have separate copies. Reference types like `List<T>` don't copy the *contents* of the object when you assign the reference; just the reference itself is copied, all copies of that reference will refer to the same object, and changes to that one object will be observed when using *any* copy of that reference.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, the problem is by the time the actions are executed the list already contains 5 elements, therefore they will all print 5 items. If what you want is to print the items that were contained when the action was added to `actions`, then you can create the `string` with the desired output and then print that `string`. Because that string is in the [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)), you'll be able to access it with the value you expect, i.e.

```cs
public static void PrintList()
{
   var actions = new List<Action>();

   var listaInt = new List<int>();

   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
   {
      listaInt.Add(i);
      var entries = string.Join(",", listaInt.Select(d => string.Format("{0}", string.Join(",", d))));
      actions.Add(() => Console.WriteLine("counterList: " + entries));
   }

   foreach (var action in actions)
   {
      action();
   }
}
```